# Master/Detail Flow Activity - code in detail part is not responding

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created a Master/Flow Activity in Android Studio for a app I'm making. I'm able to display the specified activity in the detail area of the app; however, none of the coding works.

I tried running that specified activity (without the Master/Flow) and it worked perfectly! How do I get the coding part of the activity to work. I think it needs to be fixed in the snippet of code (below) from the ItemdetailFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem.id.equals("1"))
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_music, container, false);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

If you need any other information, please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: Here a short video that I made, so it will hopefully make more sense.
[link](http://www.screencast.com/t/CfvmcHSIwt)

Comment: can you post the code of your detail activity  as well.

Comment: [link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/detailactivity.txt)

Comment: where is the code related to UI interactions ? In Fragment or Activity? can you please that too.

Comment: Manifest[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/AndroidManifest.txt) 
DummyContent[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/DummyContent.txt) 
DetailActivity[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/DetailActivity.txt) 
DetailFragment[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/DetailFragment.txt) 
ListActivity[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ListActivity.txt) 
ListFragment[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ListFragment.txt) 
Music[link](http://orenpowell.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Music.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just inflating the music layout in the ItemDetailFragment. Just inflating the layout won't bring the functionality alive. So with some liberty i have changed your Music class extend Fragment. I am adding some code below. I hope it helps, feel free to ask clarifications if needed.

ItemDetailFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
* A fragment representing a single Item detail screen. This fragment is either
* contained in a {@link ItemListActivity} in two-pane mode (on tablets)  or a
* {@link ItemDetailActivity} on handsets.
*/
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(
                ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
            container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem.id.equals("1")) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_music, container,
                false);

    }
    if (mItem.id.equals("2")) {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detail_container, new Music())
                .commit();
    }
    if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_music, container,
                false);
    }

    return rootView;
  }
 }
```

fragment_item_detail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/detail_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Music

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Music extends Fragment {

Button bttnKevin, bttnLecrae, bttnLuke;
// bttnSkillet, bttnSoMo, bttnHunter;
MediaPlayer mpKevin, mpLecrae, mpLuke, mpSkillet, mpSoMo, mpHunter;
int playing;

Button.OnClickListener bKevin = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpKevin.start();
            playing = 1;
            bttnKevin.setText("Pause");
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpKevin.pause();
            playing = 0;
            bttnKevin.setText("Play");
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener bLecrae = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpLecrae.start();
            playing = 1;
            bttnLecrae.setText("Pause");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpLecrae.pause();
            playing = 0;
            bttnLecrae.setText("Play");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener bLuke = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpLuke.start();
            playing = 1;
            bttnLuke.setText("Pause");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpLuke.pause();
            playing = 0;
            bttnLuke.setText("Play");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener bSkillet = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpSkillet.start();
            playing = 1;
            // bttnSkillet.setText("Pause");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpSkillet.pause();
            playing = 0;
            // bttnSkillet.setText("Play");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener bSoMo = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpSoMo.start();
            playing = 1;
            // bttnSoMo.setText("Pause");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpSoMo.pause();
            playing = 0;
            // bttnSoMo.setText("Play");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnHunter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};
Button.OnClickListener bHunter = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (playing) {
        case 0:
            mpHunter.start();
            playing = 1;
            // bttnHunter.setText("Pause");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            mpHunter.pause();
            playing = 0;
            // bttnHunter.setText("Play");
            bttnKevin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLecrae.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSkillet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // bttnSoMo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttnLuke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
};




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_music, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    bttnKevin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttnKevin);
    bttnLecrae = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttnLecrae);
    bttnLuke = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttnLuke);
    // bttnSkillet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttnSkillet);
    // bttnSoMo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttnSoMo);
    // bttnHunter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bttnHunter);

    bttnKevin.setOnClickListener(bKevin);
    bttnLecrae.setOnClickListener(bLecrae);
    bttnLuke.setOnClickListener(bLuke);
    // bttnSkillet.setOnClickListener(bSkillet);
    // bttnSoMo.setOnClickListener(bSoMo);
    // bttnHunter.setOnClickListener(bHunter);

    mpKevin = new MediaPlayer();
    mpKevin = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.meow);
    mpLecrae = new MediaPlayer();
    mpLecrae = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.dog_barking_sound);
    mpLuke = new MediaPlayer();
    mpLuke = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.meow);
    mpSkillet = new MediaPlayer();
    mpSkillet = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.dog_barking_sound);
    mpSoMo = new MediaPlayer();
    mpSoMo = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.meow);
    mpHunter = new MediaPlayer();
    mpHunter = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.dog_barking_sound);

    playing = 0;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, and I did have questions, but once I start reading it step-by-step and doing it myself, it started to make sense to me. Thank you, Dora.